# Android studio complains about my JAVA environmental variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My machine is ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. 
Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I download the Android studio 1.2.1.1. I create a project and try to view activity_main.xml. However, it pop up an error in the "message gradle sync" window:

```
Gradle 'HelloAndroid' project refresh failed
Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: /path to my home/Android/Sdk/bin/java
```

The suggested directory does not exist. So I set my JAVA_HOME environmental variable to /usr/bin where my system java binary locates. 
However, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is a big clue. Do you see where it says "Tried location: "...

```
Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: /path to my home/Android/Sdk/bin/java
```

That should tell you that Android Studio has a configuration option for Java's location and is not using the JAVA_HOME path variable. As I don't use android studio regularly, I'd suggest you do a quick search for the configuration location if it is no longer at File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs